# SQLAlchemy group by day in timestamp column

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have an ORM (Model) defined in SQLAlchemy as below:

```
class StoreView(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'store_views'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    store_id = Column(Integer)
    started_from = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    end_to = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    average_watch_time = Column(Float)
    total_watch_time = Column(Float)
    total_views = Column(Float)
```

I'm planning to get the sum of all views in each day and tried to group the results based on their end_to. I have used the following query in sqlalchemy:

```
result = session.query(
                StoreView
                ).filter(
                    StoreView.started_from > from_date,
                    StoreView.end_to < to_date,
                    StoreView.store_id==5
                ).group_by( sa.func.year(StoreView.end_to), sa.func.month(StoreView.end_to)).all()
```

But this query throws this error:

```
(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) function year(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

I am using the timestamp in my model and I don't plan to change it because of some reason. The only thing I can do is modify the query. The SQLAlchemy is connected to AWS Redshift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to group by the number of views per day in Postgresql the query would look like this (`WHERE` clause omitted):

```sql
SELECT end_to::date AS date, COUNT(*) AS views    
FROM store_views    
GROUP BY end_to::date    
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

The trick to dealing with the timestamp is to cast it to the date type, which truncates the value to the date part.  In SQLAlchemy the equivalent code would be

```py
with Session() as s:    
    result = s.query(    
        sa.cast(StoreView.end_to, sa.Date).label('date'),    
        sa.func.count().label('views'),    
    ).filter(    
    ).group_by(    
        sa.cast(StoreView.end_to, sa.Date),    
    ).order_by(    
        sa.text('date desc')    
    )    
    for row in result:    
        print(row)
```

Resulting in values like

```
(datetime.date(2021, 5, 4), 1)
(datetime.date(2021, 5, 3), 1)
(datetime.date(2021, 5, 2), 2)
...
```

The equivalent SQLAlchemy 2.0 style query would be

```py
with Session() as s:
    q = sa.select(
        sa.cast(StoreView.end_to, sa.Date).label('date'),
        sa.func.count().label('views'),
    ).where(
        StoreView.started_from > from_date,
        StoreView.end_to < to_date,
        StoreView.store_id == 5,
    ).group_by(
        sa.cast(StoreView.end_to, sa.Date),
    ).order_by(
        sa.text('date desc')
    )
    result = s.execute(q)
```